# Internal module as single function

Tags: module, typescript, internal

Why TS generates two functions, but not one?

It looks like we have one module separated between two files in TS:

```
module Main {
    export function P() {
    }
}
module Main {
    export function P2() {
         P();
    }
}
```

And it compile to JS as two functions:

```
var Main;
(function (Main) {
    function P() {
    }
    Main.P = P;
})(Main || (Main = {}));
var Main;
(function (Main) {
    function P2() {
        Main.P();
    }
    Main.P2 = P2;
})(Main || (Main = {}));
```

But I **need** such JS output file, so all modules content would be concatenated to single function:

```
var Main;
(function (Main) {
    function P() {
    }
    function P2() {
        P();
    }
    Main.P2 = P2;
})(Main || (Main = {}));
```

So I do not need to write additional export function to use in other parts of module with same name.

---

I know that I can write:

```
module Main {
    function F1() {
    }
    export function F2() {
        F1();
    }
}
```

But it is not a good idea, because sometimes I have very big classes and functions.

Comment: Why do you **need** this? the output in your 2nd block is completely usable JS. Help us to understand what the use case is.

Comment: @Brocco i updated my question, sorry

Comment: @Brocco, I don't know why he **need** this, but in fact, I can understand why it would be much better if Typescript compiler/bundler could be able to concat all the stuff of the namespaces into the same IIFE. I have more than 200 files using the same namespace, and the generated code gets much bigger than it would if it concated the namespace definitions. It adds ~15kb of unnecessary code. Even after gzipping and minification, that generated code is not cool.

Comment: @Buzinas excellent point! I was just trying to clarify the intent as you mention, but you bring up an excellent use case for having that feature.

Comment: @Brocco read this issue threads [link](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4652) [link](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4779) [link](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/892)

Comment: @Buzinas read this issue threads [link](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4652) [link](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4779) [link](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/892)

Comment: @Aleksey good enough! thank you! =)

Answer (score 1):

> Why TS generates two functions, but not one

Just an optimization *not done by the compiler*. Basically the `module` keyword ([now called `namespace`](http://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/project/namespaces.html)) is a *simple transform* to [a common namespacing pattern](http://addyosmani.com/blog/essential-js-namespacing/). Specifically `Immediately-invoked Function Expressions (IIFE)s` based namespacing.