# Module merging - how it works?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I've created simple typescript file - [playground link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=module%20Animals%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20export%20class%20Zebra%20%7B%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Amodule%20Animals%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20export%20interface%20Legged%20%7B%20numberOfLegs%3A%20number%3B%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20export%20class%20Dog%20%7B%20%7D%0A%7D).

```
module Animals {
    export class Zebra { }
}
module Animals {
    export interface Legged { numberOfLegs: number; }
    export class Dog { }
}
```

From my point it is equivalent to:

```
module Animals {
    export class Zebra { }
    export interface Legged { numberOfLegs: number; }
    export class Dog { }
}
```

and should generate:

```
var Animals;
(function (Animals) {
    var Zebra = (function () {
        function Zebra() {
        }
        return Zebra;
    })();
    Animals.Zebra = Zebra;
    var Dog = (function () {
        function Dog() {
        }
        return Dog;
    })();
    Animals.Dog = Dog;
})(Animals || (Animals = {}));
```

But in the playground you can see that it generates two `Animals` variables, i.e. treated it as separate namespace.

Is it correct? According [handbook](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#declaration-merging-merging-modules) it should be merged...

**EDIT**

Side note according definition file (d.ts) - when I run tsc with --declaration switch following definition is generated. Module Animals included twice. Is it correct?

```
declare module Animals {
    class Zebra {
    }
}
declare module Animals {
    interface Legged {
        numberOfLegs: number;
    }
    class Dog {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But in the playground you can see that it generates two Animals variables, i.e. treated it as separate namespace.

It does generate two variables (see "why two functions are generated and not one" [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32575302/390330) for reason). However it is still a *single namespace* (notice `Animals || (Animals = {}` means it carries over the previous value if available).

> According handbook it should be merged

They are merged. The generated code makes sure (using `Animals || (Animals = {}`) that `Animals` carries on from the *the first module declaration*. The handbook doesn't say *how* it manages this merging ([this does](http://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/project/namespaces.html)).

Comment: It seems I misunderstand how module merge works. But it still very strange for me. What if I have 100+ files in one module, then variable will be repeated 100 times?

Comment: Also, when I try to generate definition from all of my files, single d.ts file contains multiple modules with the same name and VSCode stated that this is an error

Comment: Ok, close question.Besides,  @basarat thank you on your work on typescript

Answer (score 1):

Although the typescript compiler will merge the types of the two modules, these types no longer exist in the compiled javascript (from a type-safety perspective). In javasript, only the implementation of the module matters, so the merging of the implementations happens at run time.

The two `var Animals` declarations do not conflict, and each of the functions that add members to the Animals module are called with `(Animals || (Animals = {})`. Which will either use the current value of the `Animals` variable, or set `Animals` to a new empty object, and then use that.

The fact that this happens at runtime is important, because it allows you to extend objects that are created outside of the file you're working on. For instance, you can extend builtin objects using the same syntax. Check out [this playground example](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=module%20console%20%7B%0A%09export%20function%20betterLog%28...args%29%20%7B%0A%09%09console.log%28%22WOW%22%2C%20...args%29%3B%0A%09%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aconsole.betterLog%28%22cool%22%29%3B) to see how it merging works with builtin objects.